# Spark SQL NOT operator and Null-aware predicate sub-queries cannot be used in nested conditions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The following Spark SQL query works fine:

```
((country IN (FROM medium_countries) ) AND (country IN (FROM big_countries))) AND EMAIL IS NOT NULL
```

and the following one works fine:

```
FALSE = ((country IN (FROM medium_countries)) AND (country IN (FROM big_countries))) AND EMAIL IS NOT NULL
```

but when I add `NOT` operator, like:

```
NOT ((country IN (FROM medium_countries)) AND (country IN (FROM big_countries))) AND EMAIL IS NOT NULL
```

it fails with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Null-aware predicate sub-queries cannot be used in nested conditions: (NOT (country#22 IN (list#99 []) && country#22 IN (list#100 [])) && isnotnull(EMAIL#20));;
Filter (NOT (country#22 IN (list#99 []) && country#22 IN (list#100 [])) && isnotnull(EMAIL#20))
:  :- SubqueryAlias `medium_countries`
:  :  +- Project [value#6 AS country#8]
:  :     +- LocalRelation [value#6]
:  +- SubqueryAlias `big_countries`
:     +- Project [value#1 AS country#3]
:        +- LocalRelation [value#1]
+- SubqueryAlias `users`
   +- Project [name#19, email#20, phone#21, country#22, monotonically_increasing_id() AS UniqueID#27L]
      +- Project [_1#14 AS name#19, _2#15 AS email#20, _3#16 AS phone#21, _4#17 AS country#22]
         +- LocalRelation [_1#14, _2#15, _3#16, _4#17]
```

Could you please explain why `NOT` is not working there?

Comment: I think there is a pull request here to make it possible. Not sure when they expect to update, left a comment to check in with the team. https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/22141